# Is there a collection for looking up items not only by key, but also properties of an item?

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to work out the most efficient way of finding items in my collection. First of all here is some more information/requirements:

- Order is not important.
- Must **not** look up using enumeration.
- Collection will be very large but won't be modified after it is initially
  populated.
- Must be able to look up by key (string) but also be able to look up by one of two properties of the item type.

I am currently using a custom collection which inherits from KeyedCollection, which uses GetKeyForItem() to extract a string from the item, to be used as the key, which is fine so far.

The problem is with the way I want to be able to look up items. It is my understanding that aside from 'dirty' enumeration, items are looked up using the same method as they are added, whether that's using a custom equality comparer or a key.

Am I missing something? Is it acceptable practice to create three collections with the same items but with different GetKeyFoItem() implementations for each of the properties that I want to be able to look up by? Or is there another collection that I could use?

I hope this is enough information to illustrate my question. I'd appreciate any advice you have.

Comment: You can use Linq to build Dictionaries (unique keys) or Lookups (non-unique keys)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq for this! Linq is very powerfull thing!

Here is small example...

```
    public class YourClass
    {
        public int ClassIntProperty { get; set; }
        public string ClassStringProperty { get; set; }
    }
    List<YourClass> YourClassItemsList = new List<YourClass>();

    public void SeekItem()
    {
        //Get several items
        var t = YourClassItemsList.Where(item => item.ClassIntProperty == 0).AsEnumerable();
        var tt = YourClassItemsList.Where(item => item.ClassStringProperty == "abc").AsEnumerable();

        //Get one item
        var ttt = YourClassItemsList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ClassIntProperty == 0);
    }
```

Comment: This does what I need in terms of finding the items but iterates through the collection and if the collection has thousands of items in it, will this not have a big impact on performance with frequent calls to the method?

Comment: 1) How do you want to find items in collection without iterating whole collection? O_o 2) Learn more about LINQ and query optimizations! 3) You can use you own iterator instead of Linq. If so, only experimental test wil show you if your iterator is faster than linq's! 4) If you want to look up for elemenets in VERY big collections, than you need a DataBase! 5) You can write your own type of collectin whuch will support indexes and etc, but I don`t think that such solution is for you...